# Send a mail directly without opening either mail App or mail website

Tags: html, css, forms

I want to send a mail to my company address without having a website or app opened. Also, I want to display an error that all the fields are required in case that the customer does not fill all the fields and a box that emerges telling the customer that the mail was sent successfully.

This is the code I have so far:

```html
<form method="POST" action="mailto:jorge.soto.rodriguez@outlook.com" enctype="text/plain">
  <label for="fname">*¿Cuál es tu nombre?</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname">
  <br><br>
  <label for="lname">*¿Cuál es tu correo electrónico?</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname">
  <br><br>
  <label for="country">*¿Qué artista te interesa?</label><br>
  <select id="country" name="country" placeholder="Selecciona un artista...">
    <option value="faruz">FARUZ</option>
    <option value="potencia">POTENCIA</option>
    <option value="rapder">RAPDER</option>
    <option value="rc">RC</option>
    <option value="zticma">ZTICMA</option>
  </select>
  <br><br>
  <label for="subject">Detalla aquí tu propuesta:</label><br>
  <textarea id="subject" name="subject" style="height:150px"></textarea>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

Comment: Without a website/app where do you plan to put this code?

Comment: HTML and CSS alone won't do it, you'll need a server-side language like PHP to send emails. It's probably best to install a framework and go from there (like Laravel), otherwise look up the `mail()` function or use PhpMailer, SwiftMailer, etc.

Comment: I mean, I do not want the website to open the mail server website or APP every time I click "Send". I just want the user to click on that to complete the form.

Comment: HTML and CSS won't do it alone, because up to now there is not functionality designed to perform what you really want, the only suggestion to that can be using server-side languages like PHP, Node.js , Python, or any other you may find good to use

Comment: Well, `action="mailto:jorge.soto.rodriguez@outlook.com"` is handled locally by the browser. `POST` to a server-side url and let the server send the email.

Comment: it seems like it is not going to be possible the only left option is to use server-side languages, because `mailto` is designed it away it open mailing app check this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Introduction_to_HTML/Creating_hyperlinks#E-mail_links

Answer (score 0):

as mentiond above, you need a server for this.
I have a python server and a little client that sends emails. you need a little background in networks to understand this, and if you dont have just read a little about HTTP, SMTP, AJAX etc.
server:

```
import socket
import select
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
HTTP_FORMATS = ["GET", "POST"]


def valid_http(data):
    """
    :param data:
    :return: if the http is valid and relevant to us.
    """
    temp = data.split(" ")
    if temp[0] in HTTP_FORMATS and "HTTP/1.1" in temp[2]:
        return True
    return False


def focus(data):
    """
    :param data:
    :return: the http format
    """
    temp = data.split(" ")
    if temp[0] == "GET":
        return temp[1]
    elif temp[0] == "POST":
        data = data.split("\r\n\r\n")
        return data[1]


def clean(data):
    """
    :param data:
    :return: "cleaned" data- now python can understand the data
    """
    data = data.replace("%22", '"', 100)  # we want " instead %22
    data = data.replace("%20", ' ', 100)  # we want space instead %20
    data = data.replace("%3Cbr/%3E","\n",100)
    data = data.replace("<br/>", "\n", 100)
    return data


def send_email(message, email, password,send_to_email, subject): 
try:
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = email
    msg['To'] = send_to_email
    msg['Subject'] = subject

    msg.attach(MIMEText(message, 'plain'))

    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(email, password)
    text = msg.as_string()
    server.sendmail(email, send_to_email, text)
    server.quit()
    print "sent email"
except:
    print "probably not valid email address or not blocked email"
#  that was part of a big program so thats why its in try thing.

open_client_sockets = []
server_socket = socket.socket()
server_socket.bind(('0.0.0.0', 80))
server_socket.listen(100)


email = ""  # email to send from
password = ''  # password to the email above
reciever_mail = "" 
subject = ''
content = ""
email_const_from_client = "arnav123"
while True:
    rlist, wlist, xlist = select.select(open_client_sockets+[server_socket],     open_client_sockets, [])
for current_socket in rlist:
    if current_socket is server_socket:
        (new_socket1, address1) = server_socket.accept()
        open_client_sockets.append(new_socket1)

    else:
        data = current_socket.recv(4096)
        if data != "":
            print "here"
            original_data = data
            if valid_http(data):
                data = focus(data)
                if data == "/":
                    f = open("website_file.html", "r")
                    txt = f.read()
                    current_socket.send(txt)
                    f.close()
                if data == "/favicon.ico":
                    try:
                        with open("favicon.png", "rb") as image_file:
                            a=image_file.read()
                            current_socket.send(a)
                            image_file.close()
                    except:
                        print "no favicon image in this server"
                else:
                    data = clean(data)
                    print data
                    if email_const_from_client in data:  # the user wnts to send an email
                        data = data.split(email_const_from_client)  # [0] is mail. [1] is content
                        subject = data[0]
                        content = data[1]
                        reciever_mail = data[2]
                        print subject
                        print content
                        print reciever_mail

                        send_email(content, email, password, reciever_mail, subject)

        open_client_sockets.remove(current_socket)
        current_socket.close()
```

for client side:

```
<html>
<script>
url="127.0.0.1";

function sending (var_to_send, callback){
    /*
    this is the function that every other sending/receiving function rely on
    it creates a XMLHttpRequest- sends it with the relevent data and receives data from the server
    */
     var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
     request.open('POST', url, true);
     request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
     request.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
     request.onreadystatechange = function () {
         if (request.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
               var serverResponse = this.responseText;
               serverResponse=serverResponse.replace('HTTP/1.1 200 Ok\r\n\r\n','');
               callback(serverResponse);
         }
     };
     request.send(var_to_send);
 }


function send() {
    var subject = document.getElementById("subject").value;
    var message = document.getElementById("message").value;
    var email = document.getElementById("email_to_send_to").value;
    var separation = "arnav123"; // for the server string seperation and email request     acknowledge.
    subject = subject.concat(separation);
    var to_send = subject.concat(message);
    to_send=to_send.concat(separation);
    to_send=to_send.concat(email)
    var c = function(response){
     document.getElementById('server_respone').value = response;
    };
    var v = sending(to_send,c);
}
</script>
<body>
<textarea rows="5" cols="60" id="subject" placeholder="email subject"></textarea>
<textarea rows="5" cols="60" id="message" placeholder="email content"></textarea>
<textarea rows="5" cols="60" id="email_to_send_to" placeholder="email to send to">        </textarea>
<button type="submit" onclick="send()">send to server</button>
<br />
<textarea rows="3" cols="30" id="server_respone" placeholder="server response"></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

when you will try this, you will get a security warning in your gmail. in order to cancel this you need to confirm here: [allowing less secured apps in your google acount.](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps)
I suggest you to create another gmail acount just for the project because its makes your gmail less secure.

I hope I helped :)